# Java Crear efecto "PlaceHolder" en un JComboBox

Tags: java, java-swing, combobox

**Buenas**

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto de escritorio en java con NetBeans, aun que ya he creado varias aplicaciones la verdad es que soy bastante nuevo y siempre he tenido el problema de los combobox de tener que ponerle un titulo o selección aparte con un Jlabel o algo parecido, actualmente en mi proyecto todos los componentes tienen un efecto de "PlaceHolder" y quiero lograr esto para el "ComboBox, he conseguido esta clase al parecer muy usada:

```java
public class PromptComboBoxRenderer extends BasicComboBoxRenderer {
    
    private String prompt;

    /*
     *  Set the text to display when no item has been selected.
     */
    public PromptComboBoxRenderer(String prompt)
    {
        this.prompt = prompt;
    }

    /*
     *  Custom rendering to display the prompt text when no item is selected
     */
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus)
    {
        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        if (value == null)
            setText( prompt );

        return this;
    }
 
        
}
```

Esto funciono correctamente en un proyecto en blanco:

```
package clases;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class test {
    
    private JComboBox combo;
    
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
       
    }
     
     public test(){
     
        JFrame v=new JFrame("Primera Ventana");
        combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem("Germany");
        combo.addItem("Brazil");
        combo.addItem("Japan");
        combo.addItem("United States");
        
        v.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
        v.pack();
        v.getContentPane().add(combo);
        v.setVisible(true);
        v.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        v.add(new Panel());
        v.setSize(600, 400);
        v.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        
        combo.setRenderer(new PromptComboBoxRenderer("Country"));

     }
     
    
}
```

El problema se presenta al tratar de utilizar este mismo método en un proyecto con un Jframe generado automáticamente por Netbeans que es donde yo necesito que funcione, dejo el código y explico el problema:

```java
package ventanas;

import clases.PromptComboBoxRenderer;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Jframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public Jframe() {
 
        initComponents();
        
        setTitle("CMBO Prueba");
        setSize(600,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        jComboBox1.removeAllItems();
        
        jComboBox1.addItem("Germany");
        jComboBox1.addItem("Brazil");
        jComboBox1.addItem("Japan");
        jComboBox1.addItem("United States");
        
        jComboBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        
        jComboBox1.setRenderer(new PromptComboBoxRenderer("Country"));
        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4" }));
        getContentPane().add(jComboBox1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(150, 60, 260, 40));

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Jframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Jframe().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> jComboBox1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

El problema supongo que consiste en el L&F "Nimbus" aun que he conseguido diferente errores con otros L&F , me gustaría solucionarlo con "Nimbus" siendo el mas genérico para NetBeans.

El problema consiste en que al aplicar este efecto "PlaceHolder" se pierde el color de selección al abrir el combobox de hecho se modifica también el color de fondo de las opciones o items a elegir.

Dejo Imagen de Ejemplo:

[image: Ejemplo Error]

Cuando el Efecto normal de "Nimbus" Seria el sigueinte:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He tratado de volver a darle color de selección por código pero no lo he logrado, Espero me puedan ayudar.

Gracias de antemano!.

Comment: Hola. No te puedo ayudar con Java porque no soy suficientemente fuerte en el tema. Pero, yo **uso NetBeans** como entorno de desarrollo. NetBeans es un IDE (**E**ntorno **I**ntegrado de **D**esarrollo) **no es un lenguaje de programación**. Lo que logras o no logras depende del lenguaje que usas no de NetBeans este sólo te hace más fácil usar el lenguaje. Pero no influye en lo que obtengas o como funciona lo que hiciste.

Comment: @quevedo si amigo mal-interprete, el problema es con Nimbus que es el L&F que usa NetBeans en java como preferencia